# The position vector function for a particle.

Tags: complex-numbers

The position vector function for a particle is defined by:

R= -5Cos(2πt)i + 5Sin(2πt)j

1.Determine the corresponding Cartesian equation of the path of the particle.

2.Describe the motion of the particle

3.Determine the velocity of the particle at time t=1/8

4.Calculate the speed of the particle at time t=1/8

Comment: What have you tried? What specific issues are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Bare problem statements like this that show no effort of your own look like you’re trying to outsource your homework. This question will likely get closed or simply ignored. If you’d like to attract answers instead, read through the [site tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) and [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and edit this question to include the things described there.